# CSS parent container position:relative causing children to overflow

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I am rendering a cover image from cloudinary using Next.js's [Image component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout).

```js
function PortfolioItem({ proj }) {
  return (
    <PortfolioItemContainer>
      <ImageContainer>
        <Image
          src={proj.attributes.cover.data.attributes.formats.small.url}
          layout="fill"
        />
      </ImageContainer>
      <Content />
    </PortfolioItemContainer>
  );
}

const PortfolioItemContainer = styled.article`
  min-height: 40rem;
  background-color: ${rgba(colors.$colorGreyLight1, 0.4)};
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: ${shadows.$shadowBlackHard};
`;

const ImageContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
`;
```

I've set the image container element to **position: relative** as per Next/Image documentation,

> When fill, the image will stretch both width and height to the dimensions of the parent element, provided the parent element is relative.

> Ensure the parent element has position: relative in their stylesheet.

However, this brings a problem: The text content now overflows the parent card container. Is there a way to make the card container "stretch" itself when the content inside it is too much? The **position: relative** on the image container element is mandated by Next/Image, so I cannot remove that.

Hardcoding the ImageContainer's height to something like 300px somewhat solves the issue, but it doesn't make the image responsive.

[image]

Comment: if you have grids and you need to display images with description or content better make another approach to it.  set min height for the image and then for the content maybe limit the text. make it excerpt and just put button to read more.

Comment: Why do you have to use this particular image wrapper? You are better off with a `styled.img` object-fit: cover; ` or something, if I'm being honest. There is too little context otherwise to help you here. Do you have before/after images? I'm unsure about your screenshots.